# Why are value classes restricted to AnyVal?

Tags: scala, haskell, wrapper, primitive-types, newtype

As far as I understand value classes in Scala are just there to wrap primitive types like `Int` or `Boolean` into another type without introducing additional memory usage. So they are basically used as a lightweight alternative to ordinary classes.

That reminds me of Haskell's `newtype` notation which is also used to wrap existing types in new ones, thus introducing a new interface to some data without consuming additional space (to see the similarity of both languages consider for instance the restriction to one "constructor" with one field both in [Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#the-newtype-keyword) and in [Scala](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html)).

What I am wondering is why the concept of introducing new types that get inlined by the compiler is not generalized to Haskell's approach of having zero-overhead type wrappers for any kind of type. Why did the Scala guys stick to primitive types (aka `AnyVal`) here?

Or is there already a way in Scala to also define such wrappers for `Scala.AnyRef` types?

Comment: `extends AnyVal` is just used to indicate value classes in order not to introduce new keywords/syntax and not break existing tools.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're not limited to `AnyVal`.

```
implicit class RichOptionPair[A,B](val o: Option[(A,B)]) extends AnyVal {
  def ofold[C](f: (A,B) => C) = o map { case (a,b) => f(a,b) }
}

scala> Some("fish",5).ofold(_ * _)
res0: Option[String] = Some(fishfishfishfishfish)
```

There are various limitations on value classes that make them act like lightweight wrappers, but only being able to wrap primitives is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

The reasoning is documented as [Scala Improvement Process (SIP)-15](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html). As Alexey Romanov pointed out in his comment, the idea was to look for an expression using existing keywords that would allow the compiler to determine this situation.

In order for the compiler to perform the inlining, several constraints apply, such as the wrapping class being "ephemeral" (no field or object members, constructor body etc.). Your suggestion of automatically generating inlining classes has at least two problems:

1. The compiler would need to go through the whole list of constraints for each class. And because the status as value class is implicit, it may flip by adding members to the class at a later point, breaking binary compatibility
2. More constraints are added by the compiler, e.g. the value class becomes `final` prohibiting inheritance. So you would have to add these constraints to any class who want to be inlineable that way, and then you gain nothing but extra verbosity.

One could think of other hypothetical constructs, e.g. `val class Meter(underlying: Double) { ... }`, but the advantage of `extends AnyVal` IMO is that no syntactic extensions are needed. Also all primitive types are extending `AnyVal`, so there is a nice analogy (no reference, no inheritance, effective representation etc.)